# What does Stencil Buffer use for?

Tags: c++, 3d, direct3d

I know that this something like z-buffer, taking place in the output merge stage.
And it compares the ref value and buffer value to decide whether the point can be passed.

However,I think all the effect it can implement can always be implement by a common buffer.
When we use render to texture,and use it as a shader resource view,input it to pixel shader.
Then judge and decide whether to clip the pixel manually.
The code is like this:
if(compare the values)
    clip(0);
As stencil buffer can be replaced by common buffer,we still use it.
Can that use the acceleration of the graphics hardware?(some special instructions）

Comment: Stenciling is an additional step in the rendering pipeline, so only one pass is needed to render to color buffer and stencil buffer. With color buffer, the only problem would be that color buffers has to have the same properties (format, h and w).

Answer (score 2):

The "Output merger" is the one of the critical performance paths in rendering, so it has remained 'fixed function' while many other aspects of the modern GPU have become programmable. In addition to the kinds of tests you can do with alpha blending, you can do similar tests with stencil data in the same pass:

```
struct D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC
{
    BOOL DepthEnable;
    D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK DepthWriteMask;
    D3D11_COMPARISON_FUNC DepthFunc;
    BOOL StencilEnable;
    UINT8 StencilReadMask;
    UINT8 StencilWriteMask;
    struct D3D11_DEPTH_STENCILOP_DESC
    {
        D3D11_STENCIL_OP StencilFailOp;
        D3D11_STENCIL_OP StencilDepthFailOp;
        D3D11_STENCIL_OP StencilPassOp;
        D3D11_COMPARISON_FUNC StencilFunc;
    } FrontFace, BackFace;
};
```

The stencil buffer is used for many techniques such as shadows, reflections, decaling, etc. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_buffer).

Answer (score 1):

First: yes, anything you can (or at least normally would) do with a stencil buffer can undoubtedly be done in some other way. Like most parts of a graphics card, the question is whether the extra hardware lets you do the job faster (and I'm pretty sure the answer is often yes).

For example, one thing that's fairly common, especially in things like advertising copy, is having an image that's clipped to some pre-defined shape, like the shot of the sea-shore at sunset, clipped to the outline of some writing:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tipsquirrel.com](http://www.tipsquirrel.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Sunset.jpg))</sub>

The stencil buffer makes this utterly trivial to do very quickly, in hardware. You render the text to the stencil buffer, then render the picture normally (with the stencil buffer enabled).

This is particularly effective for things like movie titles, where the text is the title/credits of a movie, and the picture is the intro to the movie, changing every frame. In this case you can set up the stencil buffer once, then re-use it for a number of consecutive frames before updating it (e.g., with the next set of credits).

Now, it's certainly true that you could do the same thing in other ways (e.g., in a pixel shader). It's also true, however, that the stencil buffer is faster and cheaper than most of those alternatives. There's also a historical fact that stencil buffers have been around almost forever--much longer than things like programmable shaders.

Comment: I've understood it.You mean that stencil buffer is earlier than programmable shaders.So it is faster but less flexible.When we want to implement a effect,we first try to use stencil.If it can't be enough,then we consider to use high-level shaders.

Comment: There's also [ARB_shader_stencil_export](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shader_stencil_export.txt). Some (older) Nvidia cards don't support it though.

Comment: Mkay [apparently](https://opengl.gpuinfo.org/listreports.php?extension=GL_ARB_shader_stencil_export) Nvidia never implemented it. Only AMD and Intel.